# Weather forecast not showing up in calendar anymore

Tags: calendars

As the title says I'm missing the weather forecast that used to be displayed in my calendar's week view. Is this a Microsoft issue or is there a problem with my phone - and if so, how can I fix that?

(Asking Cortana for the forecast works fine.)

Comment: May be some issue with microsoft...i cannot see in my calendar also..but it is working fine in my laptop outlook calendar

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your calendar settings? Seeing weather in your calendar requires location to be active at the phone level and on at the application level as well:

Calendar > `...` > settings > Preferences

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have checked both. Are you seeing the weather forecast?

Comment: Same issue here. "Use my location to show the weather and suggested places" is checked. Also occurs on Live.com calendar. Maybe (for some reason) no weather information is available for some places? Greetings from Austria!